# Ubuntu 16.04 screen smearing, Acer v3-371

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, acer

I have the Acer V3-371 laptop without external graphics card, running on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz processor. I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on this machine.

As you can see below, on the screenshots, I've got some problem with screen smearing:

[image: Screen smearing - 1]

[image: Screen smearing - 2]

I've tried to use options "Force full screen redraws" (buffer swap) on repaint, but it doesn't work.

What can I do to avoid this smearing?

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Oops, I posted a wrong command. Please replace it with `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04?

Comment: @Pilot6 isn't AU for How-To's ?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04